# Значение this при вызове функции через setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, this

```js
function f() {
  'use strict';
  alert(this);
}
f(); // выводится undefined
setTimeout(f, 0); // выводится [object Window]
```

Т. е. при вызове функции через setTimeout игнорируется 'use strict'. Почему?

Comment: Интересно, а что должно было вывестись в `alert`, если не глобальный объект `window`?

Comment: Прошу прощения, не ошибка. Выводится undefined

Comment: А какого поведения вы ожидали?

Comment: Я ожидал, что выведется undefined, как при вызове f()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

данное поведение [документировано](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

> **Проблема с "this"**
>
> Когда вы передаете метод в `setTimeout()` (или любую другую функцию), то он будет выполнен со значением  `this`, которое может отличаться от того, которое вы ожидаете. Более подробно эта проблема объясняется [в руководстве](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method).
>
> **Объяснение**
>
> Код, исполняемый в `setTimeout()`, имеет другой контекст выполнения, нежели функция, вызвавшая `setTimeout`. Для установки значения `this` вызываемой функции применяются обычные правила,  и если вы не установили значение `this` при вызове или, используя `bind`, то значением по умолчанию в `non-strict` режиме будет объект `global` (или `window`), а в `strict`-режиме значение `undefined`. Оно не будет таким же как значение `this`  функции, вызвавшей `setTimeout`.
>
> **Замечание: *Значение `this` по умолчанию в callback-методе, вызванном в `setTimeout`,  все равно будет иметь значение `window`, а не `undefined`, даже при использовании `strict mode`.***

Comment: Неплохо было бы еще  и перевести на русский...

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к [ответу @teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/827829/186999)

таймеры: [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), [`setImmediate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate) не являются частью спецификации ECMA, а предоставляются окружением.

Из-за этого их поведение, в том числе для определения `this` может отличаться в зависимости от того, где запускается код, например:

1. браузер - `window`
2. nodejs - объект таймера.

Answer (score -1):

Передайте в функцию нужный вам `this`

```
var ob = {
  name: 'Name Object',
  count: 1
};

function f() {
  'use strict';
  alert(this.name);
}

setTimeout(f.bind(ob), 0);
```

Comment: Мне кажется вопрос несколько в другом...